# Bootstrap thumbnails: how to get them aligned in Firefox and Safari (like it is in Google Chrome)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox, safari, alignment, thumbnails

I hope someone can help me with this. 
I've used Bootstrap thumbnails for pictures and a text that goes along with it. However, Internet Explorer and Google Chrome display these thumbnails perfectly aligned. 
Firefox and Safari not: the images stay perfectly aligned, but the text field within these thumbnails, right below these images are - even with the same amount of words different in height using FF and Safari. 
There's even a difference between which thumbnail is larger in height between these browsers.
What can I do to get these thumbnails aligned in the latter browsers and keep them responsive as well?

```
.thumbnail: a > button {
color: #FFF;
background-color: #5d5d5d;
border-radius: 4px;
font-size:9px;} 

.thumbnail .img-responsive {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
border-radius:2px;}

.thumbnail > h3 {
font-family: Droid Serif, serif; 
color:#5d5d5d; 
font-weight: 600;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;}

.thumbnail p {
margin-left: 2px;
margin-right: 2px;}



<section id="home" style="padding-top:100px">
```

```
                <div class="col-sm-4"> 
            <div class="thumbnail">     
            <img src="Images/Iipva7Ds.jpg" alt="photo window treatments.jpeg" class="img-responsive"/>
                <h3>Window treatments</h3>
        <p>Transform the look of your living room, kitchen and bed room with beautiful window treatments.</p>
        <p>Find the window treatment that best complements the style of your space.</p> 
        <a href="Window treatments.html"><button type="button" value="btn btn-default" class="btn btn-default" style="color:#FFF";>Read more</button></a>   
        </div>
        </div>
```

(I've got 3 thumbnails like the above (3 x col-sm-4 within the container).

Comment: ...Holy crap, IE did what was expected?!

Comment: Yes! Unbelievable, isn't it!? :)

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to edit your question to clear it up, and I need to ask: The heck are you talking about when you say: "_the images stay perfectly aligned, but the text field within these thumbnails, right below these images are - even with the same amount of words different in height using FF and Safari._" Isn't this what happens in Chrome? What's your actual problem?